# Why does using c() on a list column not work with dplyr summarize?

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I have a list-column and I would like to use `c()` for each group to combine these lists in `summarize`. This should result in one row per group, but it does not (note the code was written using dplyr >= 1.1.0):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble::tibble(group = c("A", "A", "B"),
                     list_col = list(list("One"), list("Two"), list("Three")))

df |> 
  summarize(list_col = c(list_col),
            .by = group)
```

This returns:

```
  group list_col  
  <chr> <list>    
1 A     <list [1]>
2 A     <list [1]>
3 B     <list [1]>
Warning message:
Returning more (or less) than 1 row per `summarise()` group was deprecated in dplyr 1.1.0.
i Please use `reframe()` instead.
i When switching from `summarise()` to `reframe()`, remember that `reframe()` always
  returns an ungrouped data frame and adjust accordingly.
Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.
```

**Expected Output**

```
output <- tibble::tibble(group = c("A", "B"),
               list_col = list(list("One", "Two"), list("Three")))

  group list_col  
  <chr> <list>    
1 A     <list [2]>
2 B     <list [1]>

output$list_col[[1]]
[[1]]
[1] "One"

[[2]]
[1] "Two"
```

**Alternate Solution**

You could do something like the following code. However A) it changes the row-wise type of the column and B) I would like to specifically know why `c()` does not work:

```
df |>
  summarize(list_col = list(unlist(list_col)),
            .by = group)

  group list_col 
  <chr> <list>   
1 A     <chr [2]>
2 B     <chr [1]>
```

---

Within the first group (`A`) I expected something like the following to happen to combine the two lists into one list:

```
c(list("One"), list("Two"))
[[1]]
[1] "One"

[[2]]
[1] "Two"
```

So, why does this not work? Is this a bug or is there something with the syntax I am missing?

Comment: `Within the first group (A) I expected something like the following to happen to combine the two lists into one list:`  It is already explained in the solution about the behavior of `c` applying on a variadic argument and using `do.call`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
out <- df %>% 
  reframe(list_col = list(as.list(unlist(list_col))), .by = group)
```

-output

```
> out
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  group list_col  
  <chr> <list>    
1 A     <list [2]>
2 B     <list [1]>
> out$list_col[[1]]
[[1]]
[1] "One"

[[2]]
[1] "Two"
```

-OP's expected

```
> output$list_col[[1]]
[[1]]
[1] "One"

[[2]]
[1] "Two"
```

---

Regarding the difference in `c` and `unlist`, the default arguments are FALSE/TRUE for `recursive`

> c(..., recursive = FALSE, use.names = TRUE)

> unlist(x, recursive = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)

ie. basic difference is

```
> c(list("a"))
[[1]]
[1] "a"

> unlist(list("a"))
[1] "a"
```

With more than two elements, the of a single `list`, the `...` variadic argument length is just 1 as it is a single list being passed into the `c`.

```
> c(list("a", "b"))
[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] "b"
```

the `c` is not doing anything, unless we use it with `do.call` where each element of the `list` is being passed as separate arguments

```
> do.call(c, list("a", "b"))
[1] "a" "b"
```

With the OP's example

```
> df$list_col[1:2]
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "One"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "Two"
> c(df$list_col[1:2])
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "One"


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "Two"

> do.call(c, df$list_col[1:2])
[[1]]
[1] "One"

[[2]]
[1] "Two"
```

i.e. if we do

```
out2 <- df %>% 
  reframe(list_col = list(do.call(c, list_col)), .by = group)
```

-output

```
> out2$list_col[[1]]
[[1]]
[1] "One"

[[2]]
[1] "Two"
```

Comment: Thanks, my gap in understanding was that the function is passed `list(list("One"), list("Two"))` hence `c(list(list("One"), list("Two")))` does not do anything. I thought it was passing `c(list("One"), list("Two"))`.

Comment: @LMc In the function definition, it is a variadic argument in `c(...)`, thus it can work only when you pass the arguments manually or do some kind of string evauation (eval(parse(...) or use `do.call`

Comment: Right, I understand. My confusion was more about the structure of grouped data that summarize passes to a user-specified function like `c()`.